# What does this script do? Is it malicious?

Tags: javascript

so I received an obvious phising email today with this js code in it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript1.1"> 

<!-- Begin 

    var bCancel = false; 

    function validateRegistrationDetails(form) { 
       hmrc.portal.clearFieldValidationErrors(form); 
        if (bCancel) { 
            return true; 
        } else { 
        var registrationDetailsPageMessage = new String("<p>ERROR: This page contains one or more errors. See details below.</p>")
            var formValidationResult; 
            formValidationResult = validateRequired(form) & validateMask(form) & validateIdenticalEmailAddresses(form); 
   if (!formValidationResult){
      var formName=form.name;
      var ele=document.getElementById('pageError.registrationDetails');
      if(ele){
         ele.innerHTML = registrationDetailsPageMessage;
         ele.style.display = '';      }
   }

            return (formValidationResult == 1); 
        } 
    } 

    function registrationDetails_required () { 
     this.a0 = new Array("selectedServices", "<p>ERROR: Please select at least one online service.</p>", new Function ("varName", " return this[varName];"));
    } 

    function registrationDetails_mask () { 
    } 

    function registrationDetails_identicalEmailAddresses () { 
    } 


//End --> 
</script>
```

Is it malicious in anyway, what exactly does it do with the form data. I am not that versed in vanilla javascript.  Any explanation would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: it looks like poorly coded rather than malicious. Apart from the fact that they don't know you can't send a script in HTML files...

Comment: `new Array(content)` is bad enough, but `new String(content)` is just plain WTF. Hint: the argument is a string. `language="Javascript1.1"` is just a cherry on top.

Comment: It looks like an attempt at writing a form validator

Comment: Why do people seem to think that "new Function" is better than eval?

Comment: @Tim `new Function` is better than `eval` (in the same sense as dog bites are better than box jellyfish stings). `new Function` code is isolated from the current scope. Also, it's faster to build a function once and call it several times than to eval a string multiple times. The fact that you have pieces of code as strings floating around remains.

Comment: @JanDvorak there are usually much better alternatives for both though. If I have to choose between a dog bite, a jellyfish sting and ice-cream, I will choose ice-cream every time.

Comment: @Tim `new Function ("varName", " return this[varName];")` _is_ WTF. It is equivalent to `function(varName){return this[varName]}` - which is _still_ WTF, but this time only from the architectural standpoint (especially since, in all likeliness, `this` is going to be `window`).

Comment: I won't hesitate to generalise: `new Function` with a constant argument is _always_ WTF. Without a constant argument, the percentage drops to 99.99%.

Comment: @Tim `eval` is sometimes useful for compression (read: code golf): `eval("...".replace(/f/g,"function("))` is beneficial as soon as four functions are present.

Comment: Thanks for all the help all.  The code was inside a html file attached to the file with the instructions to open in firefox and fill out the form.  Hard deleted from computer and reported phising mail to bank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've already established that it's a phishing email.

Typically phishing emails try to make themselves look legitimate by copying large chunks of code from the original website that they're trying to pretend to be (ie your bank's site or whatever). They'll then alter that code so that it sends the relevant data to the phisher rather than to the bank. They may also add fields that weren't in the original, such as asking for your PIN, etc.

However, the main point here is that the bulk of the original code is generally retained, in order to maintain the look and feel of the original site.

Therefore the chances are that the code you're seeing has actually been copied by the phishers from the original site.

There's nothing explicitly malicious about this code in itself -- it has a *lot* of badly written code, but it isn't trying to do anything wrong in this code.

Where the problem lies for the phishers here is that Javascript code is blocked by most email clients; ie regardless of its intent, the chances are that that this code won't actually work in your mail client.

But I would guess that the phishers have just taken the original form wholesale from the website and dumped it into an email without bothering to take out any javascript that might have been embedded in it.

So the short answer is: Don't worry about this code in particular, but please do delete the email.

Answer (score 4):

In all likelihood, whoever sent you this simply lifted a section of HTML and inline JavaScript from the site they were trying to pretend to be. A few lines in the code such as:

```
hmrc.portal.clearFieldValidationErrors(form);
```

suggest that they were trying to be [HMRC](https://online.hmrc.gov.uk/), with the rest of the code being simple validation of the information being entered; I'm going to guess that the content was taken from the 'Registration' section of that site

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there's nothing malicious with it, unless some script has been included outside of this script itself.